# C# TcpListener.BeginAccept and ObjectDisposedException

Tags: multithreading, sockets, c#-4.0, asynchronous, network-programming

I encounter the ugly socket management pattern in C# where I have to catch an exception when I want to stop or close a socket...

I would like to handle my sockets so the ObjectDisposedException don't pop!

I was wondering if this code would be ok

```
private TcpListener server;
private bool listening;

private void Initialize() {

    this.listening = true;
    this.server = new TcpListener(ip, port);
    this.server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(this.AcceptSocket, null);
}

private void AcceptSocket(IAsyncResult result) {

    if (listening) this.server.EndAcceptTcpListener(result);
    else ; //Nothing or maybe some cleaning if necessary?
}

private void StopListening() {

    this.listening = false;
    this.server.Stop();
}
```

As you may know, the Stop method will trigger the AsyncCallback "AcceptSocket" while the underlying socket is closed so an ObjectDisposedException will be thrown if EndAcceptTcpListener is called...
Here, EndAcceptTcpListener is never called if the callback is triggered by a TcpListener.Stop!

So, I would like to know what happens if I don't call EndAcceptTcpListener since msdn says I MUST do it but I say I DON'T WANT that ugly exception if I can prevent it!

If it's really required to EndAccept I would like to know if you have a solution to manage socket stop and close whose avoid that stupid exception!!

Comment: It is entirely normal, something exceptional happened.  There is no "CancelBeginAccept" method.  Closing the socket causes the callback to run.  You know it happened because the socket was closed thanks to the ODE.  So you catch it, clean up if necessary, and get out of Dodge.

Comment: I don't feel exceptional to close a "listening for connection" socket. You may mean that the callback proc is exceptional in a way since it's purpose is to receive connection attempts? With a flag, like in my exemple above, I know if the callback was proc by the Stop method! I could surround EndAccept with a try block for the case unlikely behaviors would lead to a callback proc while my flag == true...

Still, my question remains "Is that ok to neglect EndAccept as in my exemple? And what really happens in the deep? Are there leaks?"

Comment: *As you may know, the Stop method will trigger the AsyncCallback "AcceptSocket"* are you sure? I have never seen that. Also, I never got such an exception.

Comment: As Hans said, it is entirely "normal", I would have said "usual"... So yes, I am sure of that! If you call BeginAccept then Stop, the callback function is triggered! That is because EndAccept is usually called from the callback plus it is "required", as msdn says...
Then, if you call EndAccept while the socket is closed, which is the case after a Stop call, it ends up throwing an ODE! These are common facts, so if you don't get such exception you probably are doing things to avoid such a case as in my exemple above! But I'm wondering if that is ok with deep system and leaks concerns...